# boostrap left sidebar with content right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set my layout to show a sidebar on the left and then content on the right, the problem is the content side is showing 4 products per row not 3

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3" id="leftCol">

                <div class="well"> 
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="sidebar">
                  <li><a href="#sec1">Section 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sec2">Section 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sec3">Section 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sec4">Section 4</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <?php echo "<div class='col-sm-3'>
              content here 3 products per row (currently showing 4)
              </div>" ?>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap works on a grid system of 12 so change the class from `col-sm-3` to `col-sm-4` (12/3 = 4)

```
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <?php echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>    <!--change class to col-sm-4-->
          content here 3 products per row (currently showing 4)
          </div>" ?>
        </div>
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: this works but when reducing window size to less than 770px the products are not stacking for mobile browser, shouldnt it reduce to 2 products per row then 1 product per row as you reduce windows size?  it seems to show 3 products and then skip the reduce to 2 products, but go straight to 1 product for mobile

Comment: I recommend having a look at the grids secion here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid , 'col-xs-[number]' is for use with extra small mobile devices such as phones, 'col-sm-[number]' is for use with small devices such as tablets etc.. all explained on their website :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
  /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

  /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

  /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

  /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries